# List not defined when calling it

Tags: python, list, call

I'm trying to call a list from one function to another function called 'let_list' and then I'm just trying to execute it so I can test if my function works or not. But the issue is that I keep getting a 'let_list' is not defined.

Here is the code:

```
import random
import getpass

def player_leader():
    let_list = []
    word_input = getpass.getpass("Choose the word: ")
    for letter in word_input:
        let_list.append(letter)
    return let_list


def player_guesser(let_list):
    alreadyGuessed = []
    while let_list:
        print ("Please enter your guess: ")
        guess = input()
        if guess in let_list:
            print ("test")
            alreadyGuessed.append(guess)
        elif guess in alreadyGuessed:
            print ("You have already guess"), guess

player_leader()
player_guesser(let_list)
```

Comment: `let_list = list(word_input)` is sufficient; you don't need an explicit loop.

Comment: In fact, you don't need a list at all; `guess in let_list` will work if `let_list` is a string just as well as if it is a list.

Comment: i think I just figured it out, thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the return value of the first function to a variable in global scope before you pass it to the second function:

```
my_let_list = player_leader()
player_guesser(my_let_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the returned value, try this:

```
returned_list = player_leader()
player_guesser(returned_list)
```

Try reading about scope:

http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html